# Does hooking up an event that is self referencing cause a memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, event-handling, eventhandler

So I have a simple class:

```
public class GridButton : Button
{
    public event EventHandler OnClick;

    public GridButton()
    {
        this.Clicked += GridButton_Clicked;     
    }

    private void GridButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HandleTap();
    }
```

Now as this is a view control I am not in charge of when this object is disposed.

Is the above code a memory leak or is the `GarbageCollector` clever enough to work out that the event handler is self referencing and so doesn't cause a leak.

If this is a memory leak what is the correct solution?

Should I be using a more `WeakRefence` like the one oulined here?

http://paulstovell.com/blog/weakevents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET garbage collector will find and delete cycles (`this` -> `OnClick` -> `this.GridButton_Clicked`).

"Memory leaks" in .NET tend to occur when you have say a collection (be that a list, map, events, whatever) that will never be freed (e.g. a global/static variable, or up at the start of the stack which won't go out of scope during the program), and then you keep adding more items to that over time, but never remove them.

For example:

```
public GridButton()
{
    Globals.OnRefreshClicked += Refresh;     
}
private void Refresh()
{
   ...update text, state, whatever...
}
```

Where "Globals" is anything long-lived. Now even if you remove this button from the GUI, unless you also remove that event, the `Globals.OnRefreshClicked -> this.Refresh` reference will keep your object alive, at least as long as `Globals`, which could be until the program terminates.